# c# multiple binding label with string and data

Tags: c#, xamarin

Quick question:

How can I bind a label with fixed string itself?
Like "ID:xxxxx"   "ID:" is the fixed string and the xxxx is data
the only way i can make it is creat two label in UI.

Is there anyway can make it with one label?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For projects in the past, I've made my own custom label class with multiple bindable value properties that just concatenate the values together.

```
public class MultiLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty Value1Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value1), typeof(string), typeof(MultiLabel), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty Value2Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value2), typeof(string), typeof(MultiLabel), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty Value3Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value3), typeof(string), typeof(MultiLabel), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty Value4Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value4), typeof(string), typeof(MultiLabel), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty Value5Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value5), typeof(string), typeof(MultiLabel), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);

    public string Value1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Value1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value1Property, value); }
    }

    public string Value2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Value2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value2Property, value); }
    }

    public string Value3
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Value3Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value3Property, value); }
    }

    public string Value4
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Value4Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value4Property, value); }
    }

    public string Value5
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Value5Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value5Property, value); }
    }

    static void OnValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var label = (MultiLabel)bindable;

        label.Text = label.Value1 + label.Value2 + label.Value3 + label.Value4 + label.Value5;
    }
}
```

And in xaml

```
<local:MultiLabel Value1="ID:" Value2="{Binding Id}" />
```

The main reason we did this was to reduce the number of labels to decrease the memory footprint and the number of Values you need can always be changed it just so happens the max we ended up needing was 5.

*Update*

Nowadays I would use the built-in Formatted Text on a label.

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{ID:}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding Id}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: thanks for you help!  is there anyway to create a property like children.add that can customize the property mount?

Comment: and how can I use different BindContext while setting binding?

Comment: What do you mean by a Children.Add property and what are you wanting it to do? I'm assuming you are wanting to bind from multiple viewmodels to your values, which you can set them to the binding of another control on the page if needed `Value2="{Binding Source={x:Reference _otherViewOnPage}, Path=Id}`. If that isn't what you're trying to do then just bind your multilabel values directly to a viewmodel that has all the properties you need

Comment: This is a bit dated now and instead, I would use Label.FormattedText with Spans

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly in Xaml like this :

```
<Label Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat='ID:{0}'}}"/>
```

There is no need for a converter or another property in your view model ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a new property to output your custom format, someting like:

```
public string MyCustomFormatProperty{
    get {
        return string.Format("ID:{0}",  this.XXX);
    }
}

<Label Text = "{Binding MyCustomFormatProperty}" />
```

Another way is to use a converter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: if you use the first approach, please remember that MyCustomFormatProperty will not be notified about changes of it's base property - you'd need to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate string with fixed label string

eg: Lable1.Text=Lable1.Text+"xxxxxxx";

i think this is what you need from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Label` consisting of multiple text elements called `Span` by setting `Label.FormattedText` with `FormattedString`. Each `Span.Text` can be set through binding as well. You can even format every `Span` individually.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text for details.

An example:

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="ID:" />
            <Span Text="{Binding ID}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```